# syslog-ng starts and runs fine manually... starts but doesnt create logs when using systemd

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, syslog, selinux

Redhat 7.6 with latest syslog-ng (3.22)

ive searched and tried all the old remedies. Nothing has worked to resolve this.

My syslog-ng.conf file has a bunch of ports and a bunch of destinations. When something comes in on the port, it creates logs and folders of the destination. Simple.

If I do this from CLI as root:

```
/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F --cfgfile /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --control /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl --persist-file /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist --pidfile /var/run/syslog-ng.pid
```

Everything works. I can watch my log folder and see logs being made. No problem.

ps -ef |grep syslog

shows

```
root      7179  7166  0 17:15 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F --cfgfile /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --control /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl --persist-file /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist --pidfile /var/run/syslog-ng.pid
```

**HOWEVER**

If I run it like this (and when system starts):

```
systemctl start syslog-ng
```

Everything appears to work.
ps -ef|grep syslog

shows

```
root      7434     1  0 17:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F --cfgfile /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --control /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl --persist-file /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist --pidfile /var/run/syslog-ng.pid
```

The only difference that when run from systemd, no logs get created. I have no idea what could be causing this. Netstats shows its still listening on all of the ports.

journalctl -eu syslog-ng shows:

```
Aug 27 17:22:32 system-new systemd[1]: Starting System Logger Daemon...
Aug 27 17:22:32 system-new systemd[1]: Started System Logger Daemon.
```

**UPDATE 1 as per comment:**

1. not an selinux issue (all ports needed have been allowed)
2. same goes for firewall
3. never looked at audit log but pasted latest stop and then start below (nothing goes into audit log when I run manually)
4. I didn't try or not try to use Journald - whatever is enabled by default. I did try uncommenting ForwardToSyslog=yes in the config as per a search result I found. It made no difference.
5. also keep in mind when thinking about firewall rules etc and port issues... it DOES work when running manually, which means firewall isn't really the issue

***AUDIT LOG***

```
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1566960199.893:2253): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=syslog-ng comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1566960207.896:2263): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=syslog-ng comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

ps -efZ -systemctl

```
system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0  root      3207     1  0 19:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0  root      9499     1  0 20:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F --cfgfile /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --control /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl --persist-file /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist --pidfile /var/run/syslog-ng.pid
```

ps -efZ -manual run

```
system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0  root      3207     1  0 19:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 9543 1  0 20:34 ? 00:00:00 supervising syslog-ng
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 9544 9543  0 20:34 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng --cfgfile /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --control /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl --persist-file /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist --pidfile /var/r$
```

***Netstat***

systemctl

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10004           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10101           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10005           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10006           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10007           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10008           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10009           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10201           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10202           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10203           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10012           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10013           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10014           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10015           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10016           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10018           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10019           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10004           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10005           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10006           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10007           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10008           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10009           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10010           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10012           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10013           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10014           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10015           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10016           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10017           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10018           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10019           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10101           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10201           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10202           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10203           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*                           9645/syslog-ng
```

manual run

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10004           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10101           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10005           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10006           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10007           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10008           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10009           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10201           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10202           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10203           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10012           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10013           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10014           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10015           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10016           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10018           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10019           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10001           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10002           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10003           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10004           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10005           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10006           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10007           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10008           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10009           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10010           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10012           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10013           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10014           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10015           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10016           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10017           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10018           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10019           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10101           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10201           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10202           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10203           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10301           0.0.0.0:*                           9544/syslog-ng
```

**UPDATE 2** Audit log grep for syslogd_t

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1566959653.640:2104): arch=c000003e syscall=83 success=no exit=-13 a0=212b2b0 a1=1ed a2=ffffffffffffdcc0 a3=7ffd07da1a34 items=0 ppid=1 pid=9499 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="syslog-ng" exe="/usr/sbin/syslog-ng" subj=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 key=(null)

type=AVC msg=audit(1566959663.651:2105): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=9499 comm="syslog-ng" name="log_collection" dev="dm-5" ino=35651585 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1566959663.651:2105): arch=c000003e syscall=83 success=no exit=-13 a0=212b2b0 a1=1ed a2=ffffffffffffdcc0 a3=7ffd07da1a34 items=0 ppid=1 pid=9499 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="syslog-ng" exe="/usr/sbin/syslog-ng" subj=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Comment: Is it a SELinux problem? Does `ps -efZ` output show different contexts when you run from cmdline or from systemd? Do you see entries for AVC in /var/log/audit/audit.log? When you say it's listening on all ports, which are those? (Include netstat or, better, lsof output in your question.) Are you using journald? If so, are you forwarding messages to syslog using `ForwardToSyslog=yes` in journald.conf or using another method?

Comment: updated question with requested info... the only thing I noticed was there is a difference in the ps-efZ ... i dont really know what i means though

Comment: SELinux is not ports, it's the type in `ps -Z`. Do you see other entries in audit.log looking for `syslogd_t`? Particularly of the `type=AVC` type?

Comment: hmm.. ok. I thought it was port related because I did have do semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 10001 for each port....  see update 2

Comment: Looks like you're using a location other than `/var/log` right? That might explain it... What's the location? Try `ls -ldZ` on both /var/log and the other location.

Comment: in what way? I didnt get to specify anything. I normally don't install these kinds of apps using yum.. but I didnt see another way. I also normally use Debian.  the location the logs are being written to that im sending when it does work is /data.  on var log: drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   .

I dont really know where syslog-ng writes ITS log too... unless i run it manually in debug mode and output specificall.

Comment: on /data:   drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 .

Comment: Check `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` to see where logs are going to be written to. Suppose it's `/data/log_collection/` then change the type of that directory with `chcon -t var_log_t /data/log_collection`. You might also want to change the type of any existing log files there. In short, the SELinux policy only allows syslog (process with type `syslogd_t`) to write its logs to `/var/log` (directory with type `var_log_t`), so if you want to use a different location, you should change the SELinux type to match that of the normal log directory.

Comment: oh ok. Good explanation. so you were referring to where logs coming in are being written. Then yes its /data/log_collection/. /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf I actually wrote from scratch so I can confirm thats where i want my new logs coming in to go(which works when i manually run). There's currently no valid logs in there (other than what im sending as tests). I'll be replacing the existing "duct tape" server with this one when this works. I didnt know chcon command existed. I suppose theres no way to change the type to something else? or is that bad practice? Also thanks so far.

Comment: also... does the chcon command change ownership or anything of the files? there are other services that need to be able to read them and the dirs recursively. I have a specific standard user specified in syslog-ng.conf that gets ownership when stuff is created or added

Comment: Linux owner/group should be fine, it's separate from SELinux. Other processes are likely to be running under the "unconfined" type, so they probably won't have any problems reading from the log files (but keep an eye on `type=AVC` entries in your audit.log, whatever SELinux blocks will be logged there.) I'm going to write an answer with more details of everything.

Comment: yep.. that resolved it. thanks a lot man. ill update syslog-ng git with the info just cuz its not in the documentation anywhere that you cant use folders outside of /var/log/ without SELinux edits. even if its redhat/centos specific and/or not directly related, it really chewed up a bunch of my (and some of your) time.

Comment: You'll still want to use `semanage fcontext` to make that configuration permanent. See my answer below for more details. You're welcome! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is an SELinux problem.

RHEL and its relatives (CentOS, Fedora) typically ship with SELinux enabled.

SELinux supports programmable policies that can be customized or replaced. By default, RHEL/CentOS/Fedora use the **targeted** policy, which is a policy that doesn't limit all processes (your shell and whatever you start from it will be run with the `unconfined_t` type) but it does apply restrictions to some *targeted* daemons, of which syslog daemons (be it sysklogd, rsyslog, syslog-ng and journald) are included.

SELinux applies types to processes (that you can inspect with `ps -Z`) and to files/directories (which you can see with `ls -Z`).

It will set rules such that when a process of a specific type executes a binary of another type, the resulting process will run under that type. That's how systemd (running under `init_t`) spawns syslog-ng (binary with type `syslogd_exec_t`) will spawn a process running under `syslogd_t` (but if you run it directly, you get `unconfined_t`, as you've seen.)

Next, the policy defines what a process running under `syslogd_t` *can and can not do*. More specifically, a syslog daemon is expected to *only* write logs, so the SELinux policy defaults to only allow it to write to `/var/log` an nowhere else in the filesystem. (That way, if your syslog daemon is compromised, an attacker won't be able to use it to overwrite system binaries, as SELinux will prevent it from writing to those.)

The way this is handled is, again, through SELinux types. The `/var/log` directory has a `var_log_t` type and the policy only allows syslog to write to a directory with that type.

If you want syslog to write logs somewhere else, you should label that other location with the same type.

In your case, that location is `/data/log_collection`.

In order to set the label of `/data/log_collection` as `var_log_t`, you can use the `chcon` command.

But what you actually want to do is to make that a permanent configuration, so that this directory will always keep that context even if the filesystem is relabeled.

You can set that configuration with:

```
$ sudo semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t '/data/log_collection(/.*)?'
```

This command will update SELinux files under `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/`. It uses a regular expression for the path, in order to match the directory itself and any files under it.

And then apply it with:

```
$ sudo restorecon -R -v /data/log_collection
```

For more details, see [SELinux Contexts — Labeling Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files) at Red Hat Documentation Portal.